# How to copy a file over the network that is in frequent use?

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming

I need to copy a large file (around 20 MB) over the network.  Normally, this wouldn't be an issue, however, the file is written to fairly often (around once a second) by an application that's on the same box as the file.

So because the file is written to pretty often, `File.Copy` call fails pretty often.  I've also tried `File.ReadAllLines` which seems to work every time, but takes forever.

Is there a better, more efficient and safer way to copy the file over the network?

P.S. The file is being written to by a process that utilizes Log4Net.  And, in case anyone is wondering, the process that does the writing is out of my hands.

Comment: How often do you need to copy it? Is the process that copies in the same box? How recent do you need the network copies to be?

Comment: What is the exception that is being thrown when the File.Copy fails? How often do you need to make a copy?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fileshare field when opening the file to allow other processes access to it while you are accessing it, unfortunately if your process is not the one locking the file there is no way for you to release it and you already mentioned that you cannot change the code doing the writing, by allowing r/w in the fileshare field you can allow the other process to access the file while you are copying it.  You could write a little function to check if the file is locked and change your code so that while it is locked you keep checking until it comes unlocked and then copy it.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that File.Copy is failing to acquire an exclusive lock on the file.

Consider that `File.Move` is a quick operation, even over the network.  If the file need not remain present for the previous application, you could run a

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    try {
        File.Move(logFilePath, tempPathOnRemoteServer);
    } catch (Exception) { 
        if (i == 9)
            throw new Exception("Could not acquire lock");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * (i+1)); }
}
File.Copy(tempPathOnRemoteServer, endPathOnLocalHost);
```

Which should not have issues assuming the logging appliaction can recover from the file being moved while it is open.

Alternatively, if the file cannot be moved, use the same code as above, replacing File.Move with File.Copy, but then your exclusive lock could cause issues for the other application if the copy takes too long.

Comment: How is File.Move a quicker operation over the network than File.Copy?

Comment: File.Move is faster than copy when both the source and destination are on the same volume, as there is no transfer of data going on, just a metadata update.  Think of it as renaming the file.

Comment: I don't think that the original poster wanted to copy the file to the same volume. He/she specifically stated that they have to copy a large file over the network. In that case, there is no difference between move and copy.

Comment: That would be correct, if not for the File.Copy line at the bottom of my code sample.  The goal is to move the file to another name while retrying on failure so that if the other application has the lock, we wait until they are done, and by moving the file to a new location, they are not blocked by us once they try to re-acquire the lock as the logger will create a new file.  Once we are safely on a temp file that no-one cares about, we can take our sweet time and perform the copy.  For a 20 MB file over gig-e, the difference may be minimal - for a 20 MB file over T1, it's huge.

Comment: For us, there is no difference between File.Copy and File.Move, but for any other application that is trying to access the file, the difference allows them to continue without them being blocked.

Comment: or you could allow rw in the fileshare field when accessing the file like i mentioned earlier and other processes would still have access to the file without us having to create another redundant copy of the file locally.

Comment: Log4net defaults to exclusive access, which would still be blocked even upon specifying Read/Write sharing.  Keep in mind that cooperative sharing is opt-in.  Luckily, Log4net also does allow minimal locking, but the OP already stated that he does not have access to the application.  See http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html#fileappender.

Answer (score 1):

Read the file using the FileStream class and don't forget to set the appropriate values for FileAccess and FileShare in the overloaded constructor.

```
FileStream(String, FileMode, FileAccess, FileShare)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try dealing with it thus:

```
string pathToFile = "path-to-your-file" ;
using ( Stream     s = File.Open( pathToFile , FileMode.Open , FileAccess.Read , FileShare.ReadWrite ) )
using ( TextReader r = new StreamReader( s ) )
{
    string fileContents = r.ReadToEnd() ;
    process( fileContents ) ;
}
```

If the process that's writing to the file is unwilling to share it for reading, you're SOL, though.

However
.
.
.
You said:

> P.S. The file is being written to by a process that utilizes Log4Net.
>   And, in case anyone is wondering, the process that does the writing is out of my hands.

Is the file you're trying to access produced by a [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) Appender, like [FileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.FileAppender.html) or [RollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.html)?

If so, the default logging model is `FileAppender.ExclusiveLock`, which keeps the file open for the duration with an exclusive lock, but IIRC, it's still willing to share it for read.

But an even easier (why reinvent the wheel?) way to get the desired result (send the file over the network) is to use the [Log4Net configuration](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/index.html). You can add an appender to the source applications Log4Net config file that will help you. You can use either:

- The [RemotingAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RemotingAppender.html) "is designed to deliver events to a remote sink. That is any object that implements the RemotingAppender.IRemoteLoggingSink interface. It delivers the events using .NET remoting. The object to deliver events to is specified by setting the appenders Sink property."
- The [TelnetAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.TelnetAppender.html) "accepts socket connections and streams logging messages back to the client. The output is provided in a telnet-friendly way so that a log can be monitored over a TCP/IP socket. This allows simple remote monitoring of application logging.
  The default Port is 23 (the telnet port)."

Either way, you just need to write a simple service that will handle the inbound logging messages.

As far as efficiency goes, it would seem that, if it's log4net output, you just need to keep track of the highwater mark and copy just the new stuff.

1. open the source file for read
2. create the target file
3. copy data until end of file across the network
4. save the current position in the stream
5. sleep
6. open the source file for read
7. open the target file for append
8. seek to the remembered position in the stream (presumably no longer at end of file)
9. copy data across the network until end of file, appending to the target file.
10. repeat, *ad nauseum*, from #4

Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't modify the program that writes to the file, then your options are somewhat limited. The two possibilities that come to mind are:

Open the file exclusive, and copy it in a loop:

```
using (var fin = File.Open(InputFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
{
    using (var fout = File.OpenWrite(OutputFilename))`
    {
        int bytesRead = 0;
        var buffer = new byte[65536];
        while ((bytesRead = fin.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            fout.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
    }
}
```

You'll have to write code to handle the exception that is thrown if Log4Net has the file open for writing when you try to open it for reading. That code should just wait a moment and retry.

The potential drawback here is that Log4Net might throw an exception if it can't write to the file (because it's open for exclusive access). If Log4Net doesn't like you opening the file for exclusive access, then ...

Just rename the file, and then copy it at your leisure. If Log4Net has the file open when you try to rename, your code will throw an exception. You can just retry. If Log4Net tries to write to the file after you've renamed it, Log4Net will create a new file with that name.

I don't see any other options.

By the way, 20 MB isn't really a large file. At modern network speeds, you should be able to copy that in well under a second.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, then, another option will be to always write to two files simulationousely. One - the real, and another, with temporary name (let's say GUID).
As soon as you need to copy, stop writing to the temporary file (instead create a new one, and continue writing there). Then the file won't be locked any more, so you'll be able to upload it as slow as you wish. After only - remove it.

Answer (score -1):

What about first making a copy locally - which will be very fast and will preserve the state of it, then upload the copy, and in the end remove the copy ?

Comment: That will work, except when it doesn't. All you're doing is making the  time window for error smaller. If there's any chance that the file can be modified while being copied, then it *will* happen.

Comment: Ok, then, another option will be to always write to two files simulationousely. One - the real, and another, with temporary name (let's say GUID).